# How to stop frame layout background from showing through fragment controls?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-framelayout

I have a frame  layout with a background color set that I programmaticaly add fragments to. The fragments are smaller than the layout and I want the layout color to show around the edges of the fragments but when I add the fragments the layout's background color eliminates the background color of the frgament's parts. Is there a way where I can have the fragment's parts come to the fore and the layout color stay in the background?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the drawable background to the frame layout you are trying to inflate to the main layout::

```
<FrameLayout
  android:layout_height=""
  android:layout_width=""
  android:background="@drawable/frame_drawable">
   .....
   //Frame Layout contents
   .....
</FrameLayout>
```

Create a drawable file named frame_drawable.xml on your drawable folder::

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
                 android:shape="rectangle">

        <!--Background-->
        <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent"></solid>
        <!--Border-->
        <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@color/mainBackground"></stroke>
        <!--Radius-->
        <corners android:radius="3dp"></corners>

    </shape>
```

Comment: Perfect solution. Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad it helped. Accept the answer if it is the solution for your question. Thanks.

Comment: Got it. Thanks again.